# Space combat game with standard deck of cards

Tags: identify-this-game

About a year ago I was clicking around on the net and I found someone's personal blog with a description of an invented card game.  It was played with a normal deck of cards.  Face cards were ships, and they could be augmented with shields, phasers, torpedos etc... which were represented by the pip cards.  I've searched for hours and can't find it.  Has anybody seen this game?

Comment: I feel like i read something about this on a looney labs related blog; maybe wonderland or one of their personal blogs. Maybe a game designer's process blog?

Comment: I seem to recall it was an obscure post on a personal blog, and the game inventor played it with his kids

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it could be InterPlaNet War by John Buenavides. His description:

> 54 cards. The deck will have markings on the corners equivalent to a
>   standard deck of playing cards. Each player takes a suit to represent
>   his army: Martians (Spades), Terrans (Diamonds), Jovians (Clubs), or
>   Venusians (Hearts). One card will represent your home Colony, the
>   other 12 cards represent your Cohorts -- your combat units

And looking at the pics, the face cards are indeed marked as ships. And some of the cards reference torpedoes.

Here's [his post on the BGG forums](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/616507/littlebox-interplanetary-war-quick-space-navy-war) back in 2012. The links he provides to PnP files are all google drive links, though, which seem to be private now.